# Proving a sequence with a factorial is Contractive

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

yn= 4^n/n!

we are taught to do the following

absolute value {y_n+2 - y_n+1}/ absolute value {y_n+1 - y_n}

I'm getting stuck as I get to absolute value {4^n+2/(n+2)! - 4^n+1/(n+1)!}/ absolute value {4^n+1/(n+1)! - 4^n/n!}

but I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Just a side note that each n must be greater than 4 for this to be contractive, as $|y_{4} - y_{3}| = 0$.

Comment: btw absoulteValue(a)/absoluteValue(b) = absoluteValue(a/b) assuming that a and b are not both zero

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both numerator and denominator by $(n+2)!$, and divide both by $4^n$ to get

$$\frac{|16 - 4(n+2)|}{|4(n+2) - (n+2)(n+1)|} = \frac{|4n-8|}{|n^2-n-6|}= \frac{|\frac{4}{n} - \frac{8}{n^2}|}{|1 - \frac{1}{n}-\frac{6}{n^2}|}$$

The numerator goes to 0 and the denominator goes to one, so the fraction goes to 0.  That means that for any $0 < r < 1$, the fraction will eventually be less than $r$, so the sequence is contractive.

If you want to avoid taking the limit, one can observe that for $n \ge 10$,

$$1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{6}{n^2} \ge 1 - .1 - .06 = .84$$

and

$$ \frac{4}{n} - \frac{8}{n^2} < \frac{4}{n} \le .4$$

so the ratio will be less then $1/2$ for all $n \ge 10$.

Comment: not looking to take the limit I need to show absolute value of (4n-8)/absolute value (n^2-n-6) is less than some number r < 1

Comment: That's not true in general.  The best that you can prove is that it is true for sufficiently large n,  and that is always true when the limit goes to 0. (for any value r > 0)  But if you insist on not using the limit, I can amend the answer.